# C# -- Safe Multiple Thread Save File Access

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, save

I am currently developing a **C# application** that uses **two separate threads**, the first is the **main thread** which the program operates on and the second is the **log thread**. The log thread is basically a **loop that runs every second or so** and breaks only when the application is being closed.

Basically, every second or so, the log thread writes to a log file (text file) if there are messages to output. My problem is, on the main thread I have a move function which can change the path to the log file (and other files) and it moves the old files to the new location. My problem is, what happens if the log thread is writing to the log file and the move function tries to move the file or vice versa? And how would I help prevent this from happening?

The program runs fine if I don't change the save path but I am worried that the main thread and log thread may become deadlocked if they both try to do something to the log file at the same time. I've done some research into this but all I can come up with are ways to stop multiple threads from reading/writing to a file at the same time, not moving the file and writing to it like I am. So really, is there some way that the log thread can tell the main thread it is using the log file and the main thread can use the log file when it is done or vice versa?

Multi threading is something I have always wanted to try but was always put off by the complexity of things like this. It certainly requires much more logic to stop things from going wrong.

Help would be greatly appreciated as this is one of the last things that the application needs in order to prevent massive errors (at least that I can tell, that's what testing is for really).

Edit:
What I am really looking for is **some way that the two threads can "communicate" to tell each other when they are accessing the log file** so that they don't try to access the same file at the same time.

Comment: Access to the file at the same time won't cause a deadlock .. it very well might cause other issues though. Also what is meant by "change save path"? Is that just changing the location used for the file (eg. a variable), or trying to move the file itself? (Normally windows doesn't allow moving files that are opened.)

Comment: Anyway, if this were my program - and I were limited to this general design - I would have all access to the file(s) done on the "log thread". The main thread can make a setting change, but such a change would only be processed on one thread. Using proper thread-safety to pass this information to the logging thread is still important but this eliminates the issue of multiple threads (within the same program) interacting oddly over processing the same files.

Comment: Most common way to "prevent massive errors" is to use existing solutions - there are plenty logging libraries around. Consider to clarify your goal (as far as I understand logging is just an example you trying) and show small sample of what you've learn so far with highlighted places you are concerned about. (i.e. it is somewhat hard to see how basic `lock` could not protect your operations)

Comment: @user2864740 yes, the location is changed by changing a String variable. Changing it so the log file is only accessed by one thread would require some code overhaul (because of how other code works)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am still understanding locks but I will take a better look into them and see what I can do

Comment: @JoshH One simply change is then to have the log thread monitor the "shared setting" (make sure the field is volatile) and when it changes take the appropriate internal action (the logging thread has it's own local location/file information so the shared setting is only to pass data *into* the logging thread). All the file access is done on the logging thread; the main thread simply updates configuration that will be used on a subsequent pass. Alternatively, don't allow this sort of "dynamic behavior", but pin the setting on startup or similar.

Comment: @JoshH Using a lock is to control mutual-exclusive access to a shared resource (eg. if many threads were writing to the same Stream, which is wrong for other reasons..) and is something I suggest is not required or even an issue for this particular task. Make the logging component (and it's thread) responsible for all log file work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question guides this in the wrong direction, you might get a better answer if you explain what your end goal is.

Usually this is done differently. Multiple threads log to an in memory buffer. Each thread has its own buffer, so there is no buffer contention. When the buffer of a thread is full, a new buffer is created and swapped with the full buffer. Logging continues to the new buffer, while the old buffer is sent to a thread whose purpose is just to write buffers to files and rotate the log files. This allows multiple threads to log in memory very fast. Since it's only one thread that actually interacts with the file, there's no conflict around the file movement operation.

Regarding your question, assuming file moving does not happen often, you could use a slim multiple reader, single writer lock https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to achieve that (if you have multiple threads logging and only one moving the file), otherwise if you have just two threads, a plain lock(obj) statement will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I would just kill your log thread all together whenever your main thread needs to copy the files, and then start a new log thread afterwards.